# Parsing tagless text regex / BB codes - PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a BB codes project using preg_replaces/matches aka regex, now i'm faced with a problem dont really now where to go from here: i want to encapsulate all empty text fields using paragraph elements,

Example structure

```
[article]
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio nihil excepturi quo impedit, beatae neque repudiandae temporibus sit rerum ullam.</p>
[table=lorem, lorem, lorem]  
[table-item]loremA, loremB, loremC[/table-item]  
[table-item]loremD, loremE, loremF[/table-item]  
[/table]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio nihil excepturi quo impedit, beatae neque repudiandae temporibus sit rerum ullam.
[/article]
```

so it would become something  like:

```
[article]
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio nihil excepturi quo impedit, beatae neque repudiandae temporibus sit rerum ullam.</p>
[table=lorem, lorem, lorem]  
[table-item]loremA, loremB, loremC[/table-item]  
[table-item]loremD, loremE, loremF[/table-item]  
[/table]
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio nihil excepturi quo impedit, beatae neque repudiandae temporibus sit rerum ullam.</p>
[/article]
```

Comment: But no text is actually "tagless" in the example though? The text you've put in paragraphs are still in the `[article]`-tag. Do you mean that you want to find all text that doesn't start with a tag on the same line as the text?

Comment: OK... and what do you need help with? Where is the preg_replace code you have so far, and what happens when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

`^([^\[].*?[^]])$` - Match all lines that does not start with `[` and does not end with `]`: [Example](https://regex101.com/r/k9YxWj/1)